# Configuração de e-mail localhost XAMPP

Tags: xampp

Fiz uma configuração de e-mail em um formulário de contato pelo WordPress e adicionei um *link* `mailto:xxxxx`. Ele já está na página definida, porém não me leva a lugar nenhum. O que eu preciso configurar dentro do *XAMPP* para que habilite esse formulário?

Comment: Depende do navegador etc. Recomendo: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17517600/9101590

Answer (score 0):

Use o [FakeSendMail](https://www.glob.com.au/sendmail/) para envio a partir de sua máquina local de desenvolvimento, configurando:

1 - Descomente a linha abaixo do arquivo php.ini, e digite o path correto:
***sendmail_path = "C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"***

2 - Configure conforme sua necessidade, por exemplo:

**smtp_port**=587

**smtp_ssl**=tls

**smtp_server**=smtp.gmail.com

**auth_username**=meu_email@gmail.com

**auth_password**=minha_senha

Deve funcionar dessa forma.